# Is it possible to send an SMS over Wifi?

Tags: android, sms, android-wifi, smsmanager

I'm working on an Android application in Android Studio and wanted to add a feature that allowed a text (SMS) message to be sent from the application to a mobile phone number.

I found one way to do this by using the SMS Manager API, but it seems like this only works if the application is run on a cell phone with a SIM Card/Data plan. I'd like the user to be able to send a text over WiFi in case they're running the application on a tablet with only WiFi or another device that only has access to a WiFi connection. The application would only send messages to a mobile number, and doesn't need to worry about receiving texts back from said mobile number.

My initial research proves that it is not possible to send SMS messages over WiFi. My question is, is this actually the case? Or does anyone know of a way to do this over a WiFi connection? Even if I don't use SMS, I'd like some other way to get a message from the device to a mobile phone number. I just figured that SMS would be the most straight forward.

Comment: SMS is a technology in the mobile phone network. There's nothing similar in WiFi as far as I know, but of course various services are built upon internet connectivity. (Like WhatsApp etc.). You might find a web site/service that allows sending SMS.

Comment: `... My initial research proves that it is not possible to send SMS messages over WiFi. My question is, is this actually the case?` **YES**, it is. You already answered your own question.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen: Thanks for your response. I hadn't realized that SMS was a mobile phone network only technology. My confusion came because I saw a lot of tutorials out there to send SMS using SMS Manager for emulators within Android Studio. I'm developing on a tablet that has WiFi only, so I'm not able to test out if the feature works with an actual phone number. Something like WhatsApp was what I was thinking could be done. Regardless, thanks for your patience and understanding.

Comment: @Fantômas: thanks for your response. I wasn't sure if what I wanted to be done could actually be done. I hadn't realized that SMS was a mobile only thing consider I've sent texts over WiFi before on my previous Android phone, and apps like WhatsApp exist..

Comment: Apps like WhatsApp, Telegram, TikTok, Instagram, FaceBook, Twitter, ... use the Internet, not the mobile (voice) connectivity. SMSs exist since the era of the "dumbphones"

Comment: @Fantômas I see what you mean, I understand now. Thanks. I'll try to find another way to do what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to pay for the service, you can use something like Twilio's Programmable SMS which does let you send text messages via calls to a REST API: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out. Not sure if I'll need to do that yet, but its good to know that there are some options. The feature wasn't critical for my app, but a "nice to have" feature. It still works over a data connection, but not over WiFi. I'll have to weigh the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a library for Android utilising Twilio's SMS API. It is a paid for service as the previous comment stated, however, doesnt require sim or data plan.

Hope this helps.

https://github.com/hihi-dev/android-twilio-sms

Comment: thanks for that. it's good to know that I have some options if I do decide to add this feature to my application.